# Display Calendar in Woocommerce Booking

Tags: calendar, woocommerce

I am using the new Woocommerce bookings and would like the calendar to be displayed permanently, instead of having users click the "choose" option that then displays the text.

I am too much of a novice to display pictures in this foru, so here is the [link](http://memovercph.dk/product/urban-tour/) instead.

I would like the bottom one to be displayed permanently.

The source code looks like this:

```
<fieldset class="wc-bookings-date-picker wc_bookings_field_start_date">
<legend>Start Date: <small>Choose...</small></legend>
<div class="picker" data-availability="[[&quot;days&quot;,{&quot;6&quot;:true}],[&quot;days&quot;,{&quot;4&quot;:true}],[&quot;time&quot;,{&quot;from&quot;:&quot;11:30&quot;,&quot;to&quot;:&quot;13:30&quot;,&quot;rule&quot;:true,&quot;day&quot;:0}]]" data-default-availability="false" data-fully-booked-days="{&quot;2014-6-8&quot;:[true]}" data-min_date="+0d" data-max_date="+12m"></div>
<label>
    <input type="text" value="2014" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_year" placeholder="YYYY" size="4" class="required_for_calculation booking_date_year" />
    <span>Year</span>
</label> / <label>
    <input type="text" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_month" placeholder="mm" size="2" class="required_for_calculation booking_date_month" />
    <span>Month</span>
</label> / <label>
    <input type="text" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_day" placeholder="dd" size="2" class="required_for_calculation booking_date_day" />
    <span>Day</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you figured this out yet or not, but Bookings now has a selection button to always show the Datepicker. Edit your Bookings product, and on the General tab, next to **Calendar display mode** select **Calendar always visible** from the drop-down menu. That should do it, no coding needed!